# Facebook chat framework for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, chat, xmppframework

I'm trying to create an app using Facebook chat facility. When I went through the forums I could see that I have to download XMPPFramework, I have went through the following links [1](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout), [2](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/), but not getting any idea what should I download. Please give some direction to move on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go thru these ,

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/IntroToFramework

http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

And also download mercury and install that.Then follow the steps in this link http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout to get the clone of project

These links no longer work as the project is moved to github.
This is the base link:
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework
HTH

Comment: one more, what about the download of the framework? http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout this one? but which file should i download?

Comment: You will find total set of package there in the XMPPFramework folder.Also u get the sample code in Xcode folder

Comment: hi, i found the farmework folder, but i couldn't download it. Please help. I'm now at http://www.google.com/codesearch#RPymCkaCyDk/trunk/Chatlas/Classes/ChatController.h&type=cs here. Can't move on, I forgot to add I'm trying to create an iphone app

Comment: Once u installed mercury, U just type "git clone https://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/" in your terminal

Comment: Downloaded it and ran the link in the terminal, its successfully completed the steps and received all files. But where I can find the downloaded XMPPFrameWork in my machine?