# How to send custom message to one friend using iOS facebook-graph-api?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I have a [philosophy multiplayer question-answering](https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/exphil/id632618052) app that allows players to play against each other answering questions about philosophy and ethics. For signup i allow facebook-login. I have a list where a player can invite his facebook friends to play. Its done with a request to the app-backend with all players friends, and return which have installed the app.

For those who dont yet have installed the app, i want to let the player invite them to install the app. I haven't found a way to do this with iOS graph API. Is it possible when a player taps a friend (i have the fbID), to send a message with some custom text and a link to download the app?

[image]

With the webdialogs method it does not seem to allow custom text send to one specific player. And that method opens a new window with friend selection. I don't need that as the user allready has selected a friend to invite. Is there a way to use FBWebDialogs to do this, or any other method in the Facebook iOS API?

```
[FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
     title:nil
     parameters:nil
     handler:nil]
```

Comment: For requests that are “invites” (to a user that has not installed the app already), the message part of the request is not shown by Facebook intentionally.

Comment: Have you figured this out at all?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to set up a simple XMPP server on your server and send it using their XMPP login which you can get with the following code snippet.

```
if (![FBSession.activeSession.permissions containsObject:@"xmpp_login"]){
        [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewReadPermissions:@[@"xmpp_login"] completionHandler:^(FBSession * session, NSError * error){
            if (!error){
                [self functionThatCommunicatesWithServerAndSendsXMPPLoginInformation];
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }];
    }
```

There are some nice frameworks that make XMPP really easy to implement on a simple level, such as SleekXMPP for python/django.

It's definitely a little work to do this, but probably much more effective.  Just don't spam.

For more guides (although I think a little outdated):

[Facebook chat framework for iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647590/facebook-chat-framework-for-iphone-sdk)